# Can I use Google Drive instead of a Server

Tags: android, database, server, backend

I am creating my first Android application. This will be something like a Diary or Notebook.
Andorid part is almost done and I don't know what should I do next.
Should I use data base, server....
Or can I use Drive API instead of both?
Thank you

Comment: A database is often software that runs on a server (in other words, it isn't one or the other). Google Drive, however, is not a database

Comment: That doesn't stop you from trying something, though. https://developers.google.com/drive/android/

Comment: @cricket_007 "A database is software that runs on a server." not necessarily, you can use some sqlite db on the android device

Comment: @RC. Excluding In-memory databases / flat-files :)

Comment: @cricket_007 :) For the OP: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Speaking of SQLite, does the app *need* to be connected to the internet? Why re-invent the wheel and instead [integrate with Evernote for example](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-android)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't necessarily need to use the Internet. I would do it local, but I want user be able to use the application from any smartphone. So, user should be registered.

Comment: My suggestion: use Firebase, https://firebase.google.com/?hl=es-419, login and storage, also includes sync.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a note or a diary app, your better off using some sort of database, whether that's a local SQLite database on the device or a remote database.

If remote it will need some sort of web service to communicate with the database as Android doesn't support connecting to remote mysql databases such as MySQL.

Whether the database is local or remote, it doesn't matter but this would be the better option. If it is stored in the database you can store and retrieve the meta data more easily, such as creation time, title, etc whereas in Google Drive you would either need lots of files or store the data in 1 file in a particular way that you can then parse to get the meta data out.

You could however, export the data from a database and store that on Google drive that can be used as a backup/restore option.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on the perennial rdbms vs networked filesystem approach.  Many large projects I have worked with have used both, even together.  Usually an RDBMS gives you more flexibility and easier development, while a networked filesystem approach works better when you are working with other tooks which expect file-level access.

The simple answer is yes you can but it probably is not worth it. You end up having to do a lot of work yourself to implement what SQLite can offer you.  And in the case of Google Drive, latency will likely be a killer.

So keep your data local and fast.  And work with something that gives you the flexibility you need.